# John Smilga ES6 Slider 'Uncaught ReferenceError: position is not defined' where position is a variable I use in an if statement

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, es6-modules, es6-class

I am following this tutorial on Youtube to make an ES6 slider: https://youtu.be/V26mqoNncO4 and the final code is here in the final folder (but I am working in the setup folder to follow the tutorial): https://github.com/john-smilga/javascript-basic-projects/tree/master/16-ES6-slider.

I am trying to use an if statement to change the variable 'position' to 'active' if the slideIndex is equal to 0, and 'last' if it is equal to 3. However, once I make an if statement, my browser no longer displays each slide object from the people array (the app.js file doesn't return anything), and I get the following Error:

"Uncaught ReferenceError: postion is not defined"

My app.js file:

```
import { people } from './data.js';

const container = document.querySelector('.slide-container');
const nextBtn = document.querySelector('.next-btn');
const prevBtn = document.querySelector('.prev-btn')

// set slides
container.innerHTML = people.map( (person, slideIndex) => {
console.table(person);
console.log(slideIndex);

const { img, name, job, text } = person;

let position = 'next';

if(slideIndex === 0 ){
postion='active';
}
if(slideIndex === people.length - 1 ){
postion = 'last';
}

return `<article class="slide ${position}">
<img 
src=${img} 
class="img" 
alt=${name}/>
<h4>${name}</h4>
<p class="title">${job}</p>
<p class="text">
${text}
</p>
<div class="quote-icon">
<div class="fas fa-quote-right"></div>
</div>
</article>`;
})
.join('');
```

My index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>ES6 Slider Setup</title>
    <!-- font-awesome -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css"
    />

    <!-- stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="slider">
       <div class="reviews">
         <h2><span></span> reviews</h2>
       </div>
       <div class="slide-container">
       </div>
       <!-- prev + next btns -->
       <button class="btn prev-btn">
         <i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i>
       </button>
       <button class="btn next-btn">
        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
      </button>
    </section>
    <script type="module" src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My array (in seperate js file):

```
export const people = [
  {
    img:
      "https://res.cloudinary.com/diqqf3eq2/image/upload/c_scale,w_200/v1595959121/person-1_aufeoq.jpg",
    name: "peter doe",
    job: "product manager",
    text: `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem quoeius recusandae officia voluptas sint deserunt dicta nihil nam omnis? `,
  },
  {
    img:
      "https://res.cloudinary.com/diqqf3eq2/image/upload/c_scale,w_200/v1595959131/person-2_ipcjws.jpg",
    name: "susan doe",
    job: "developer",
    text: `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem quoeius recusandae officia voluptas sint deserunt dicta nihil nam omnis?`,
  },
  {
    img:
      "https://res.cloudinary.com/diqqf3eq2/image/upload/c_scale,w_200/v1595959131/person-3_rxtqvi.jpg",
    name: "emma doe",
    job: "designer",
    text: `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem quoeius recusandae officia voluptas sint deserunt dicta nihil nam omnis?`,
  },
];
```

Comment: there's a typo in your js `postion` should be called `position`

Comment: wow that is so embarrassing!! made it harder than it was